# Pass POJO in paramater

Tags: java, methods, parameters

Assuming this is my pojo:

```
public class POJOFoo{}
public class POJOFoo2{}
```

Assuming this is my method and i want to either use the same method to 
display POJOFoo and POJOFoo2.

```
public void Foo(Object pojofoo/pojofoo2) {
    ObservableList<pojofoo/pojofoo2> observableDescriptions = 
         FXCollections.observableArrayList(new LinkedList<>());
}
```

I'm seriously out of imagination of how can I find solution on this situation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: You need to clarify your question so we can understand what it is you want to achieve and what your issue is. You have rejected to valid answers so far with a comment that makes little sense.

Comment: please check again guys if it would make sense.

Comment: POJOFoo and POJOFoo2 are completely unrelated and you need to relate them somehow. This can be done by having them both extend the same super-class or implement the same interface. The latter is the preferred approach.

Comment: i wont use both of them(POJOFoo,POJOFoo2) in the same method. i want to make a fixed but will allow both POJOs to be able to use the method.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to store both POJOFoo and POJOFoo2 together in the same list (observableDescriptions in your example) or do you want to store them separately in two lists but use the same method (Foo(...)) to store them? If it is the first case you need an interface, if it is the second then you can use generics as discussed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the datatype of the parameter `pojofoo` from `Object` to `POJOFoo` in the signature of the method.

```
public void Foo(POJOFoo pojofoo) {
    ObservableList<POJOFoo> observableDescriptions = 
         FXCollections.observableArrayList(new LinkedList<>());
}
```

In case, you want to use `Generics` to allow the method to use any `POJO`, you could probably rewrite the function as -

```
public <T> void Foo(T pojofoo) {
    ObservableList<T> observableDescriptions = 
         FXCollections.observableArrayList(new LinkedList<>());
}
```

Comment: sorry for the unclear example but my goal is want to make it reusable to other classes of pojo also.

Comment: @KurtRuzell - You may want to use an approach involving `Generics` to deal with the situation. Check the updated answer for more clarity.

Comment: wow! thanks! but how about if this is the case?                            
 public static void test(TableColumn<Object, String> tc, Object obj, 
Object obj2  String str)                                                                          {
        tc.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<obj, 
        obj2> param1)  -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(str));
        
    }

Comment: @KurtRuzell - It would still follow the same approach -

`public static <T, U> void test(TableColumn<Object, String> tc, T obj, U obj2 String str) { 
    tc.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<obj, obj2> param1) -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(str)); }`

In case of a question other than the original one, kindly create a new post for the question going forward to maintain community etiquette. If the answer solves the original question, mark this as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks sir! highly appreciate it! you are the hero of the day!

Comment: one last thing sir. why does this one doesnt work? public static <T> void tcValuePropertyObjectString(T object,  String str) {
        tc.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<T,String> param1)  -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(""));
    }

Answer (score 0):

Kurt, when passing an object as a parameter, add this object type to the method, like so:

```
public void Foo(POJOFoo pojofoo){
    ObservableList<POJOFoo> observableDescriptions = 
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(new LinkedList<>());
}
```

Comment: sorry for the unclear example but my goal is want to make it reusable to other classes of pojo also.

Comment: If you want the method to take any object, you can specify a parameter of Object, like you did in your question. Or if you want your method to take only certain types of objects, you can specify that it takes a certain superclass (for instance if you have a class Animal that is extended by Dog, Cat, etc), or that it takes a certain interface (like Map, then it will take HashMap, TreeMap, etc). Otherwise please clarify your question?